# Chartkick is not loading on Ruby on Rails 7 installed with Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, chartkick

I have installed Chartkick according to the instructions [in their official page](https://chartkick.com/). However, after trying to render a pie chart it simply says "Loading" on the div the graph was supposed to load.

- I inspected the console and am not seeing any errors.
- My data grouping is correct, from my query I get the proper hash returned.
- Rails version 7.0.5, Yarn 1.22.19, npm 8.11, pnpm 8.9.2
- When I ran yarn add chartkick chart.js I got the following warnings: warning `chart.js@4.4.0: The engine "pnpm" appears to be invalid.` This even after I installed pnpm

I am unsure what is wrong with my setup or why the graphs are not loading.

````
<%= pie_chart Income.group(:income_description).count %>```

This is the graph I am trying to generate
````